# Calling a funciton into the event handler utilizing GUI builder interface on NetBeanse

Tags: java, user-interface

So below is what i have right now, and when i test it out in the GUI the item price just changes from 0.00 to 0.0. I've tried at least 3 different ways so far of creating objects and calling them with the method calcPrice() but nothing has been successful so far. The only step foward i have made is that now the GUI stays open without crashing.

~let me know if you need more of my code to evaluate this. I only copied this part of the GUI

```
 private void DoubleBurgerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
   ItemPrice.setText(String.valueOf(price));
}                                            
           public double calcPrice(boolean singleBurg, boolean doubleBurg, boolean cheese, boolean bacon, boolean meal)
   {

      price=0;
      if (singleBurg)
      {
          price+=3.50;

      }
      if (doubleBurg)
      {
          price+=4.50;
      }
      if (cheese)
      {
          price+=.50;
      }
      if (bacon)
      {
          price+=1.25;
      }
      if (meal)
      {
          price+=4.00;
      }
      return price;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The String.valueof() will convert 0.00 to 0.0, you can use String.format to format the output with 2 digits after the decimal point.

```
 private void DoubleBurgerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
   // ItemPrice.setText(String.valueOf(price));
   ItemPrice.setText(String.format("%.2f", price));
}
```